# xdan/datetimepicker How to Highlight days?

Tags: datetimepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

We are using [this Date Time Picker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) ("jquery-datetimepicker": "2.4.0"). Site is using knockout.

There is mentioned about hilightning day`s in GitHub site, but I did not found any sample in documentation or google.

In example we get from endpoint day list in which data exists. And we want to hilight these days in calender.

**Ho to hilight days? Please provide some example... Thanks**

**Update** [Did some working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q5m9rPlZO2SKhKTRErUQ)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    timepicker: false,

    // 'd/m/y'format is requared for datetimepicker days HIGHLIGHT function to work!!!
    formatDate: "d/m/y",
    highlightedDates: [
      "01/09/2016,,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "02/09/2016,,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "03/09/2016,,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "06.09/2016",
      "07.09.2016",
      "08.09.2016",
      "12.09.2016,Christmas Eve,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "13.09.2016,Christmas Day,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "14.09.2016,Christmas Day,xdsoft_highlighted_mint",
      "26.09.2016,,xdsoft_highlighted_mint"
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example can be found here, https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/pull/262 (found in the Issues section after a search of the github repo for "highlight")

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
 formatDate: "d.m.Y", 
 highlightedDates: [
    "29.04.2015,Meeting with Pete", 
    "24.12.2015,Christmas Eve,xdsoft_highlighted_mint", 
    "25.12.2015,Christmas Day,xdsoft_highlighted_mint", 
    "26.11.2015,Thanksgiving"
 ],
 highlightedPeriods: [
    "27.04.2015,08.05.2015,Business trip", 
    "11.07.2015,31.08.2015,Summer holiday 2015,xdsoft_highlighted_mint", 
    "21.12.2015,01.01.2016,Christmas holiday 2015"
 ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks... Only need to upgrade package (my v2.4.0), nad these highlight if I am correct is implemented from v2.4.7

Comment: Maybe some one know how to solve this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763406/after-updating-xdan-datetimepicker-from-2-4-0-to-2-5-4-datetimepicker-is-und